# Anonymous methods in common lisp

Tags: methods, common-lisp, clos, mop, generic-function

I want to save a generic function as a variable:

```
(defvar *gf* (make-instance 'standard-generic-function)
```

But when adding a method I have to define `call-next-method` and `next-method-p` myself:

```
(add-method *gf*
            (make-instane 'standard-method
                          :function (lambda (args next-methods)
                                      (flet ((call-next-method () ...)
                                             (next-method-p () ...))
                                        (apply (lambda () ...) args)))))
```

How do I call a method to define `call-next-method`?
Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

See [MAKE-METHOD-LAMBDA](http://lispm.de/docs/amop/dict/make-method-lambda.html).

If you Google for it, you will find various informations about the function. For example [MAKE-METHOD-LAMBDA considered harmful](http://www.p-cos.net/documents/make-method-lambda.pdf).